# getting runtime exception while running a jar

Tags: java, exception, jar, executable

I created a jar file which contains a main class and its dependent jar.
I wrote my own manifest so that I can also include the dependencies.
The problem comes when I try to run the jar file; it gives me the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook
```

here is the folder structure

```
ExcelCopy.jar
|
|-com/utility/ExcelFormat.java
|
|-lib/poi-3.9.jar
|
|-META-INF/Manifest.mf
```

Manifest.mf content

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/poi-3.9jar
Created-By: 1.7.0_25 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: com.utility.ExcelFormat
```

Comment: If require anything do let me know

Comment: what does your `Manifest.txt` look like? Also, it should be renamed to `MANIFEST.MF`.

Comment: sorry for the typo, I have posted the content of Manifest file.. pls have a look

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to bundle lib/poi-3.9.jar within your ExcelCopy.jar. Remove it from the JAR, then you will have:

```
ExcelCopy.jar
|
|-com/utility/ExcelFormat.java
|-META-INF/Manifest.mf
```

Then you have:

```
ExcelCopy.jar
lib/poi-3.9jar
```

Running "java -jar ExcelCopy.jar" shall work.

Comment: but the ExcelFormat class is using poi-3.9.jar. If I remove it from jar then how the class will run?

Comment: Leave it outside of the ExcelCopy.jar. In my projects, I use a lot of third-party libraries, it is a common practice to refer them outside of your own JAR.

In your file system, you will have something like:

    c:\mydir\ExcelCopy.jar
    c:\mydir\lib/poi-3.9jar
Then run "java -jar ExcelCopy.jar" from c:\mydir. The relative path is specified in Class-Path of your MANIFEST.

Comment: shuang now the current folder structure is d:/ExcelCopy.jar d:/lib/poi-3.9.jar But still I am getting the same error

Comment: Try java -cp . -jar ExcelCopy.jar. This is to specify the classpath to be the current folder you execute the JAR. If this won't help, verify your poi-3.9.jar does contain the class that cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx @shuang. I tried simple logic and it worked
I extracted the required classes from poi-3.9.jar so now I have a folder call `org` in which all the required classes are.

```
ExcelCopy.jar
|
|----com/utility/ExcelFormat.java
|
|----org/apache(long dir structure)
|
|----META-INF/Manifest.mf
```

and content of `Manifest.mf`

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: org
Main-Class: com.utility.ExcelFormat
```

Now my jar is running. :D

Comment: While this works, I strongly suggest to use the solution provided by Shuang. It's neater as your classes are packaged in your own Jar file and all the necessary dependent Jar files are referenced separately, without mixing anything. If you want to package all of this in one file, just tar or zip the enclosing folder.